# onClick bind to Url.ActionLink only works first time

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I have a `Url.ActionLink`, that when clicked, I want to load a partial view into a modal.  This works the first time, but the second time it redirects the browser to the partial view instead of loading it into a modal, and the `modal()` call has an error saying that it is `undefined`.

The html for the div is:

```
        <div class="modal fade" id="modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body" id="modalBody"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The code for the binding/loading so far is:

```
$(".actionLink").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#modalBody").load(e.target.href);
        $("#modal").modal('show');
        return false;
    });
```

The error that I'm getting before the redirect is on the `$("#modalBody").load(e.target.href);` and the error is `"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function."`  It works the first time a link is clicked, so I don't know why it would be undefined the second time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .on() type of binding works only with the elements which was created before the script has been initialised.
So if you load some content dynamically in the on click function, the on() binding won't work for that content.
One solution could be if you bind the click event to the container element, where you load the new content, something like this:

```
     $("#container").on("click", ".actionLink", function(e) { ... });
```

"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on()"
[jQuery .on() doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I added the html to show the div that I am trying to display as a modal.  The actual content is held in a partial view. The html and the javascript are on the same page.  There is a list of links and the intent is that when a user clicks a link, it will load the partial view into the div, then display the div as a modal.  The modal() is not working the second time, instead it is redirecting to the partial view.  Unless I misunderstand you, the element is already on the page, I'm just looking to re-use it.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle?

Comment: As it turned out, there wasn't a problem with the code itself.  The problem was that I had manually included jQuery in the partial view, and it was breaking after the first go.  I fixed it by removing the jQuery include, and instead using jQuery to inject the javascript into the partial view after it had loaded.